# There is any possibility to approach label with EditText in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-design-library

when i put 2 or 3 TextInputLayout, label seams link graphically to previous editText instead of next. i need to put much marginTop to TextInputLayout. there is any possibility to approach label with EditText?

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

[image: example]

in this example we can see margin from hint and edittext

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the `paddingTop` of the `EditText` should fix it, for example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely add properties to `TextInputLayout` however you want it to be. Following will help you to add `marginTop` from exactly above `View`of `TextInputLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:inputType="textCapWords" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```